# How can I estimate a kalman gain matrix from system identification method?

Tags: control-theory, estimation, optimal-control, kalman-filter, system-identification

Assume that we have the input data $u$ and output data $y$ and we want to estimate a state space model
$$\dot x = Ax + Bu\\ y = Cx$$

But we want also to find the kalman gain matrix $K$. 
I found a document that explain how to estimate a state space model and at page 9 [Eigensystem Realization Algorithm](http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/SystemID/CourseNotes/EigensystemRealization.pdf) it shows that if we estimate a model  like this

$$\dot x = \bar Ax + \bar Bu\\ y = Cx + Du$$

Where $\bar A = A + GC$ and $\bar B = [B+GD, -G]$, then we can find the matrix $A, B$ because $G$ which is the kalman gain matrix in this case, it is known from the estimation. If the dimension if the output $y$ is 1 then the $G$ will have the column size 1 as well.

I wrote an algoritm called Okid.m and it can estimate a state space model from input and output data, very easily. It's one of my favourite algorithms beacuse it fits so many different types of data.

But I want to extand it so it will generate a kalman gain matrix as well.
[MataveID](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid)

Can I only change the input so $U = [u; y]$ and $Y = [y]$ and then estimate as normal? Is that so easy, or have I missed something?

Comment: From your question I understand that you want to find the $K$ matrix in the kalman filter. I have been reading "Fundamentals of Kalman Filtering: A Practical Approach Book by Paul Zarchan" and it goes through the derivation involved. Starting from the state space equation to the fundamental matrix $\Phi(t)$ then the Riccati equation form of the kalman filter. Is your question related to finding the $K$ matrix for any arbitrary system?

Comment: @SPRajagopal Hi! Have a look at MataveID. There are OCID and OKID there. They can estimate a kalman gain matrix from data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $K$ in this system is not the Kalman gain. It is a weight matrix to determine the influence of the noise on the states.

If you know the noise perfectly well, then it can be considered as an input, as you wrote in the last equation. And also if you have a way of estimating $A,B,C$ given $u,y$ of the extended system then you don't need a Kalman filter at all. Because if the estimated $A,C$ turns out to be observable, then you can uniquely calculate $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you think about this way to estimate the kalman filter? http://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/SystemID/CourseNotes/EigensystemRealization.pdf look at page 29 between equation 27-29. Can this be a solution? I estimate a stochastic model $\bar A = (A+GC), \bar B = [B+GD, -G], C, D$. Then I can find $A, B$ from $A = \bar A -G*C$ and $B = \bar B -G*D$ ?

Comment: So the idea is creating an observer first to estimate the system matrices. As I understand you chose $e=y-\hat{y}$, which is output estimation error so $K$ becomes the Kalman gain. However, you need to know $A,B,C$ to calculate $K$ (or $G$ for that matter) and this document doesn't explain how to do that.

Comment: The document explain how to estimate a state space model from data. If I have different output, then I can estimate a state space model and then reduce it and recieve the matrices. Have a look at my library how to estimate a model from OKID. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid

Comment: I didn't understand how your OKID algorithm is any different then estimation without Kalman gain. Maybe you can explain that in the question. Also, if you already have an OKID algorithm, what is your question exactly?

Comment: My question is if I can estimate a kalman filter if I know the noise. I asked this question yesterday and I have done some own research by my self and found out a method. So I think it would fit to ask something about that too. My okid algorithm does not estimate a kalman gain. So if I would change my question (which I will do). The question would stand "How can I estimate a kalman gain matrix from system identification method?"